Icons disappeared and expo image picker also not working in react native
I am working on expo-managed react native project. I am also using expo-sqlite for database purpose. Suddenly all icons from all screens in my project disappeared and expo image picker which was working fine earlier and picking images, suddenly not picking images, not even opens gallery. Is expo-sqlite responsible for it?
For reference, package.json file dependencies-
"dependencies": {
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^6.6.3",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.17",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.3.29",
    "expo": "~50.0.14",
    "expo-image-picker": "~14.7.1",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.11.1",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-hook-form": "^7.51.2",
    "react-native": "0.73.6",
    "react-native-fs": "^2.20.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.14.0",
    "react-native-paper": "^5.12.3",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~3.6.2",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.8.2",
    "react-native-swipe-list-view": "^3.2.9",
    "expo-sqlite": "~13.4.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0"
  }

Image Component- import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { Image, View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import {TouchableRipple } from 'react-native-paper';
import * as ImagePicker from 'expo-image-picker';


export default function ImageInput({handleImage, image}) {
  
  const pickImage = async () => {
    let result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
      mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.Images,
      allowsEditing: true,
      aspect: [4, 3],
      quality: 1,
    });

    console.log("image picking:", result)

    if (!result.canceled) {
      handleImage(result.assets[0].uri);
    }
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      
      <TouchableRipple onPress={pickImage}  rippleColor="rgba(0, 0, 0, .32)" background={{color:'cornflowerblue', radius:70, borderless:true}} >
        <Image
       style={styles.image}
         source={image ? {uri:image} : require('../../assets/camera.png')}
          />
      </TouchableRipple>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({

  container: {
    alignItems: 'center'
  },

  image: {
    height: 100,
    width: 100,
    borderRadius: 100,
    marginTop: 30,
    marginBottom: 30,
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});

